# Strange behavior using "for in" loop on global "this" object

Tags: javascript

Can somebody please explain what causes this strange behavior in for-in loops on the global `this` object?

In global space, do

```
for(var key in this) key;
```

The result is, `this` gets is assigned a new property `key` that has a value `"key"`.

This happens in nodejs and rhino js engine, but in a browser the result is - the `window` gets assigned a new property `key` that has a value of `"dispatchEvent"`

I thought it was some side effect of typing directly in the console, but it does the same if you run it in a script without a console with this command.

```
$ node -e "for (var key in this) key; process.stdout.write(this.key + '\n')"
```

Then I thought it had something to do with the body of the for loop just being `key;` but the same thing happens when you do

```
for (var key in this) console.log(key);
```

The things I don't understand are

1. why is `this` given a new property?
2. why is the value a string even I never give any string values?
3. Also, why is it different in a browser? (if not self explanatory given answers for 1 and 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is this given a new property?

```
var key // == this.key in the global scope.
```

because `this` is the global scope,`window` in the browser,`global` in nodejs,when you declare a variable in the global scope it will be added to the global scope ,It makes perfect sense.

> why is the value a string even I never give any string values?

because `for ... in` enumerate object enumerable property names as strings.
Now you are getting `dispatchEvent` because it is the last enumerated property in this.

> Also, why is it different in a browser? (if not self explanatory given
>   answers for 1 and 2)

How is it different in the browser? the browser has the exact same behavior,

open the console , try var `foo="bar"` ,then type `console.log(this.foo)` .you'll get bar.

Comment: Holy crap `var key` why did I not see that! Thank you!,

Comment: +1 : "enumerate object enumerable properties as strings" you mean "object property names **are** strings". :-)

Comment: Ah, so `dispatchEvent` is probably internally assigned after the loop starts and before it finishes.. probably related to printing to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Because JavaScript doesn't have block scope, it has function scope. so the expression `var key` will be declared in the `global` scope, since you are executing inside it.

And it get the value `"dispatchEvent"` because it is the last iterated property name in global `this`.

for example try the following in browser console:

```
for (var key in window.location) 
    console.log(key);
```

the last enumerated property will be `"reload"`, and as a result the variable `key` will be `global` variable and it will has the value `"reload"`.